# data representation in mysql tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

Let's say I have three tables in a mysql database that contain some data like this:

```
- Sections (which have a number, a title)
- Sub-sections (which also have a number and a title but the title is the same as the title of the next data type with is 'statements')
- Statements (which have a number, a title (the same as the title from Sub-sections)
```

As you can see above, the field **title** from both tables **subsections** and **statements** are the same and they have the same data. Is there a better way that I can represent this in my tables so that I won't have that duplication of data?

Thanks for any advice

Comment: Look up normalisation http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/normalization.htm

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [***normalize***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your tables.

You can do this using only two tables; the `sections` and subsections tables will be represented using only one table `Sections` with a new column `ParentSectionNumber` indicating the parent section for each section, the root section will have `NULL` as the parent section number. Something like this:

**`Sections`:**

- `SectionNumber`,
- `SectionTitle`,
- `ParentSectionNumber`(Nullable) Foreign key references the same table.

---

For the second table, I am guessing that, there are statements for each section or sub sections, in this case create a foreign key that references the table `sections`:

**`Statements`:**

- `StatementNumber`,
- `SectionNumber` FOREIGN KEY references `Sections(SectionNumber)`.

Answer (score 1):

Any redundancy can lead to data corruption: if there are two pieces of data that represent the same information, and one of them changes, you suddenly don't know which one is correct. Effectively, you have lost the information!

That's why **normalization** is important: it minimizes redundancy (and dependency).

Sometimes, redundancies are made on purpose for performance reasons (so called "denormalization"), but this is always done after measuring the impact on performance and carefully weighing that against the risk of data corruption. Unless you have done that, your "default" approach should be to avoid redundancies in your data model.

You haven't explained what your data model is supposed to *mean*, but I'm guessing you'll need something like this:

[image]

Note that statement has no title. You can get statement's title by JOINing `Statement` and `SubSection`.

*NOTE: If you anticipate you'll need less or more than exactly two levels of sections, you can represent that via "adjacency list", as [proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15821072/533120) by Mahmoud Gamal. For some other ways to represent the hierarchical data, take a look at [this presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data) by Bill Karwin.*